# Using objects as Map keys in Haxe

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to make a `Map` with an object as a key. The problem is, that when I try to get elements from this map, I always get `null`. It's because I'm not providing the exact same reference as the key was. I'm providing an object with the same *values*, so the reference is different.

Is there any way to solve that? Can I make it use some kind of `equals()` function?

```
class PointInt
{
    public var x:Int;
    public var y:Int;

    ...
}
```

```
var map = new Map<PointInt, Hex>();

var a = new PointInt(1, 1);
var b = new PointInt(1, 1);

var hex_a = new Hex();

map[a] = hex_a;
var hex_b = map[b];

/// hex_b == null now because reference(a) == reference(b)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706464/haxe-3-map-only-retrieves-null) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haxelang/F9Ovh7KS6rs/ENuF8qtb-GgJ), `Map` in Haxe works using the reference of the object as the key.

What you want to use instead is a [`HashMap`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/ds/HashMap.html) like this ([try.haxe link](https://try.haxe.org/#d5D63)):

```
import haxe.ds.HashMap;

class Test {
    static function main() {

        var map = new HashMap();
        map.set(new PointInt(1, 1), 1);

        trace(map.get(new PointInt(1,1)));
    }
}

class PointInt
{
    public var x:Int;
    public var y:Int;

    public function new(x:Int, y:Int)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public function hashCode():Int
    {
        return x + 1000*y; //of course don't use this, but a real hashing function
    }

    public function toString()
    {
        return '($x,$y)';
    }
}
```

What you need to change in your code, besides using `haxe.ds.HashMap` instead of `Map` is to implement a `hashCode : Void->Int` function in your key object

Since you're using an object that has 2 ints, and the hash map is just 1 int, it will happen that 2 `PointInt` will have the same hash code. To solve this you could create a hash map that uses strings as hashcode but if you can write (or google) a good hash function you will get better performance.

Comment: So what I did by now, is changing ObjectMap<PointInt, Hex> to ObjectMap<String, Hex>. I've made some simple hashing function to string in PointInt class. It's slow but it does what it has to. Maybe there will be other options one day. =]

Comment: Is it possible that the hashCode function is required to yield unique results for different objects? http://try.haxe.org/#B753E To my understanding, a HashMap should use the hashCode function for bucketing, but not for differentiating objects.